# Printing execution time, two decimal points

Tags: c, performance, time

I'm using the following function to estimate the execution time (performance) of a function:

```
double print_time(struct timeval *start, struct timeval *end)
{
    double usec;
    usec = (end->tv_sec * 1000000 + end->tv_usec) - (start->tv_sec * 1000000 + start->tv_usec);
    return usec / 1000.0;
}
```

Simple Code:

```
struct timeval start, end;
double t = 0.0;
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
... //code
gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
t = print_time(&start, &end);
printf("%.2f", t);
```

Why when I print the variable I see the time formatted in this manner: `3.613.97`? The problem is related for the two points. What means the first point and the second point? Normally I always saw just one decimal point to separate the digits.

Comment: Can you provide full minimal code which reproduces the issue?

Comment: Can be that you run it twice and because you don't have a `'\n'`/`' '` you see two floating point numbers without a space between them (`3.61 3.97`)?

Comment: @AlexLop. I'm feeling an idiot ahahah. Thank you so much. The problem was that one.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the right headers:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

At the beginning of the program:

```
clock_t starttime = clock();
```

At the end of the program:

```
printf("elapsed time: %.3f s\n", (float)(clock() - starttime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

This works on several platforms (including Windows with MinGW-w64), but the resolution of the timer (`CLOCKS_PER_SEC`) may vary per platform.

Note that this measures the clock cycles used by your application, instead of the time passed between start and end.
So while it is not an exact chronometer, it gives a better idea of how much time your program actually took to run.

Comment: what about the time expressed in milliseconds? Further as you know, it is suitable even on ARM? What about the resolution of CLOCKS_PER_SEC on ARM architectures (i.e. Cortex family)?

Comment: By the way, I compared your approach with mine and basically it is absurd that I have very substantial differences in terms of performance evaluation. Now the question is: what is the true performance evaluation between mine and your approach? It seems that mine it is more realistic but I don't know.

Comment: Note that the `clock()` delta isn't exactly the same as the elapsed time, but rather the time the CPU spent in your application. See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clock-function-in-c-c/

Comment: Yes I know. I read several sources about this debate. For your experience, what is the standard approach to evaluate the performance evaluation regarding the execution time of a function/operation?

Comment: I use the `clock()` method, but that's a personal opinion.
What I like about it is that if I have other processes hogging CPU I'm still able to get a a decent measurement of performance.

Comment: `(float)(clock() - starttime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` converts `clock() - starttime` to `float` and then likely performs a `float` division.  Then it coverts the `float` quotient to `double` as part or a ... argument before passing to `printf()`.  For a better answer, consider using `double` right away with `(double)(clock() - starttime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.